# Using EntityFramework6 to store a list of subclasses

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Using EntityFramework6, I wish to store a list of subclasses in a MS SqlServer.
Perhaps best explained with example.

What are my options?

Can I store Children in a single table with {ClassType NOT NULL, Id NOT NULL, Order NOT NULL, Quantity NULL, Price NULL} ?
We do some manual querying in dbs so I'm thinking that is preferred.

Upgrading to EF Core is NOT currently an option!

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Order {get;set;}
}

public class Specific1 : Base
{
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
}

public class Specific2 : Base
{
    public int Price {get;set;}
}

public class Owner
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Base> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: You are right, Aluan, it does. I just didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was looking for here:
https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

In short, I need to configure as follows and it more or less works out of the box:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
                .Map<Specific1>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(1))
                .Map<Specific2>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(2));
}
```